# jquery validation messages not match

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation, webforms

I have a problem with jquery validation in ASP.Net. I don't know why.
I have a form validate to test below :

```
 <form id="testForm" onload="ChangeName()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username: 
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUsername" name="txtUsername" required />
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email: 
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" TextMode="Email" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="validate" OnClientClick="ValidateForm()" />
</form>
```

here, jquery validate code

```
  function ValidateForm() {
        $('#testForm').validate(
            {
                rules: {
                    <%=txtUsername.UniqueID%> : {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 6
                    },
                    <%=txtEmail.UniqueID%> : {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    }

                },
                messages:
                    {

                        <%=txtUsername.UniqueID%> : {
                            required: "Must input username",
                            minlength: "Max length are 6 charators"
                        },
                        <%=txtEmail.UniqueID%> : "Is not email fomat"
                    }
            });
        }
```

But, result is not match with message :
[Click here to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hcra.png)

Comment: Looks like the browser is performing client-side validation based on the `required` attribute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223332/html5-input-required-how-to-disable

Comment: I tried to do it. but I can't show the different. :(

Comment: Also, don't you need to add *ClientIDMode = Static* to your username textbox?..

Comment: @Khazratbek : I tried to do it. but I can't show the different :(

Comment: have you tried to delete *required* parameter?

Comment: @Khazratbek, I tryied to deleted required parameter, result : no message show.